# SQL Left Join returning more records than expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am trying to join two tables `dbo.contact` and `dbo.notes` using the `contactno` column, when I only run the query for dbo.contact

```
SELECT     
    contactno, date_recd
FROM         
    dbo.contact
WHERE     
    (date_recd > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
    AND (date_recd <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

I get 11526 records but when I join it with the `notes` table

```
SELECT     
    dbo.contact.contactno, dbo.contact.date_recd, dbo.notes.noteline
FROM         
    dbo.contact 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.notes ON dbo.contact.contactno = dbo.notes.contactno
WHERE     
    (dbo.contact.date_recd > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (dbo.contact.date_recd <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

then I am getting 22276 records. I am not sure what is going on wrong. I want to only get all 11526 how to do that? Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: there may be more than one `noteline` per `contactno`

Comment: @vkp but I am asking it only give me all the columns from contact table shouldn't it only return 11526 records and where it doesn't exist it should be null right??

Comment: remove `noteline` from the query and see the difference

Comment: what is the primary key of `notes` ? Include that in your query result also. You should see for one `contactno` there are multiple pk of `notes`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, doing a left join returns all the rows from the first table and only matching rows from the second table.  However, if more than one row from the second table matches, it will return both, which can cause duplication of the rows in the first table.

For example:

```
Table1
ID  Value
 1      A
 2      B
 3      C

Table2
ID  Value
 1      X
 1      Y
 2      Z

Select * from Table1 a
left join Table2 b
on a.ID = b.ID
```

Returns:

```
ID  Value    ID  Value
 1      A     1     X
 1      A     1     Y
 2      B     2     Z
 3      C  Null  Null
```

Which has a total of four rows, even though `Table1` in the example only has three.  To avoid this, you either need to adjust your join criteria so each row has at most one match, or add some unduplication steps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only one note per contact, you can use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT c.contactno, c.date_recd, n.noteline
FROM dbo.contact c OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 n.*
      FROM dbo.notes n 
      WHERE c.contactno = n.contactno
     ) n
WHERE (c.date_recd > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND
      (dc.date_recd <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-01 00:00:00', 102));
```

Normally the subquery would have an `ORDER BY`, specifying which note you want.  However, your query doesn't specify which of multiple notes is the preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

The Above Answers Were Fantastic but I wanted to post the code that fixed my issue. So I needed all the 11526 records but not only the top 1 noteline for each contact I wanted all the notelines so I ended up concatenating the records to a single string.

```
Select  contact.contactno, 
STUFF(( Select '' + notes.noteline  FROM notes
 Where notes.contactno = contact.contactno 
order by notes.contactno for xml path (''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') AS Notes 
From contact
WHERE 
(contact.date_recd > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
 AND
(contact.date_recd <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-04-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
Group By contact.contactno;
```